# XSLT regular expression to accept only few characters in a string

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, special-characters

I am writing a regular expression which will allow only below special characters:

```
- _ * & . , #
```

I wrote below function which will avoid all the characters except mentioned in below pattern:

```
<xsl:function name="wd:allowed_characters">
    <xsl:param name="input_param" />
    <xsl:if test="$input_param !=' '" >
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace($input_param,'[^.#, \- _ * a-zA-Z0-9]',''))" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

My problem is whenever I try to add `&` in the pattern at any place, I got below errors:

> Severity: fatal
>   Description: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity
>
> Severity: error
>   Description: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

I want to know about how can I add `&` in the pattern like other special characters?

Comment: Try declaring a variable after param: `<xsl:variable name="ampp" select='"&amp;"'/>` and build the regex string like `concat('[^.#, \- _ * a-zA-Z0-9', $ampp, ']')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is written in XML, so the source code of your XSLT stylesheet must be well-formed (and generally also valid) XML. In XML there are five special characters: `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, `'` which roughly can only be used as follows:

- Inside attribute values, you must escape quotes if the quote is also the bounding character, as in `test=" &quot;foo&quot; "`. Often you can write an attribute value by surrounding it with the other quote: `test=' "foo" '` or `test=" 'foo' "` are both valid. In XPath, which is typically written in XSLT inside an attribute value, this is a common way to write string literals (this is what you are already doing in your code above).
- Either in attribute values or any other place where free text is allowed, you must always escape `<` and `&` in `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively.
- The `>` never needs to be escaped, but many people do.
- The five "escapes" are always available as named entity references, regardless of the presence of a DTD: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`, other named entity references first need to be declared in a DTD (as is often done for `&nbsp;`).
- Only inside a `CDATA` section (and in a comment) you do not need to escape any of these characters: `<![CDATA[<hello>&]]>` is exactly the same as `&lt;hello>&amp;`. CDATA sections are only allowed in text nodes, not in attribute values.

It is often confusing. If the source document contains `&lt;` in the XML, you won't be able to find it by comparing it to a string `&lt;`, because essentially it's just the `<` character. Instead you must search for `<`. However, since XSLT is written in XML, writing `<xsl:if test="contains(.,`<`)"` will search for the `<` character, not the four-character string `&lt;`.

In regard to your question, you can write your expression simply as follows:

- `replace($input_param,'[^&amp;.#,_*a-zA-Z0-9-]','')`
- I've removed the spaces (not sure that was intentional)
- I've place the `-` at the end, where it does not require escaping
- Your `xsl:if` is redundant: the `normalize-space` will make a string consisting of only spaces the same as the empty string. With or without the `xsl:if` will have the same results

Note: because of the complexities of escaping, quote-issues and other things, it is common to write a regular expression in a variable's sequence constructor, to prevent those issues to happen in the first place (added the x-modifier to allow whitespace in the regex):

```
<xsl:variable name='regex' as='xs:string'>
    [^&amp;.#,_*a-zA-Z0-9-]
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:function name="wd:allowed_characters" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="input_param" as="xs:string" />
    <xsl:value-of select="
       normalize-space(
       replace($input_param, $regex, '', 'x'))" />
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Superb explanation, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge, in XML, we can't use direct key of '&', which should be combination of '&[A-z0-9]+;'. In XML we can use either '&amp;' or '&#x0026;' entity formats.
In regex '[^.#, &amp;&#x0026;- _ * a-zA-Z0-9]' can be used.

Comment: Yes, `&` is not allowed in XML directly.